# OSX 10.8.1 update problem

Tags: macos, mac-mini, software-update

I have a brand new Mac Mini.  It came (last week) with OSX 10.8.1 installed.  Software update is reporting an update for iPhoto to version 9.4.2.  When I try to run the update, it fails with a message saying that I need OSX 10.8.2.  Then when I try to download the OSX 10.8.2 release, I get a message 'OSX Mountain Lion is not compatible with this computer'.

What is happening?!

Comment: The OSX 10.8.2 update for my Mini was reinstated Nov 30 and seems to have worked OK.  That allowed the iPhoto upgrade to run as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the update was pulled after problems with the update.